# Resources for determining if Metasploit has exploit for given CVE

Tags: metasploit, cve

Are there any reliable resources for finding whether or not a Metasploit exploit exists for a given CVE?

I have found [CVE Details](http://www.cvedetails.com/) to be woefully out of date with regards to keeping this information up to date.

Comment: I've found that googling for "metasploit CVE-xxxx-yyy" works pretty well

Comment: You can use http://www.rapid7.com/db/search to search Metasploit modules online.

Comment: There is also a nice search page in http://www.securityfocus.com/vulnerabilities

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The most reliable source, is probably [Metasploit's vulnerability & exploits DB](http://www.rapid7.com/db/search) - But some alternate sources do exist:

- You can use [Exploit-DB search](http://www.exploit-db.com/search) to search by CVE exploits by "metasploit" e.g.:

  http://www.exploit-db.com/search/?action=search&filter_page=1&filter_description=&filter_exploit_text=&filter_author=metasploit&filter_platform=0&filter_type=0&filter_lang_id=0&filter_port=&filter_osvdb=&filter_cve=**[CVE]**
- You can use [OSVDB.org](http://osvdb.org/search/advsearch) to search by CVE e.g.:

  http://osvdb.org/search/search?search[vuln_title]=&search[text_type]=titles&search[s_date]=&search[e_date]=&search[refid]=**[CVE]**&search[referencetypes]=CVEID&search[vendors]=&search[cvss_score_from]=&search[cvss_score_to]=&search[cvss_av]=*&search[cvss_ac]=*&search[cvss_a]=*&search[cvss_ci]=*&search[cvss_ii]=*&search[cvss_ai]=*&kthx=search

  and check the references section for a Metasploit URL.

It's worth noting that both those sources are usually a day or two behind the Metasploit repo.